# Momentum representation of a state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, fourier-transform

I am trying to figure out the momentum representation of the state which has the properties
$$\langle \psi |\hat q |\psi \rangle=-q_0,$$
$$\langle\psi|\hat p|\psi \rangle=p_0,
$$$$\Delta q\Delta p=\hbar/2.$$

My approach to this was going to show that this is a Gaussian, because it obeys the minimum uncertainty principle.  This would result in a Gaussian centered at $-q_0$.  But for momentum, the Gaussian produces an expectation of 0, so is there something that I am missing here?

EDIT:::

So this is what I have so far.  A gaussian centered at $-q_0$
$$A e^{-(q+q_0)^2/2}e^{i p_0x/\hbar}$$

This would have a momentum distribution centered at $p_0$ according to the fourier transform, correct?

Comment: Hint: How is a translation of a function implemented in terms of the Fourier transformed function?

Comment: Hint 2: So you tried with wave functions of the form $Ce^{-a(x-d)^2}$. But what if you choose $d$ to be complex? (And then try a Fourier transform to put everything in a momentum repr.)

Comment: @yankeefan11 Comment after the edit: You are almost done! You found the correct wave function (apart from a small factor 2 typo, which I will correct in your answer now), it is $A e^{-(q+q_0)^2/2}e^{i p_0x/\hbar}$. However, this is the correct wave function in *coordinate space* representation. To transform this wave function into *momentum space* representation, you still have to Fourier transform it (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space), and then you are really done.

Comment: Does the factor of 2 really matter as long as I normalize properly.

Comment: @yankeefaan Sorry, now I see that the condition actually is only $\Delta x \Delta p= \hbar/2$ (like for squeezed coherent states). So you are right, the factor of two actually doesn't matter. It is a different state, but it still satisfies your conditions. In fact, any state of the form $A e^{-a(q+q_0)^2/2}e^{i p_0x/\hbar}$ will satisfy your condition! (But don't forget we are still in coordinate space representation.)

Comment: Alright that makes sense.  Thanks for the help (now just to do that fourier transform...)